# How to parse json with mixed nested and non-nested structure?

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, nested, apache-spark-sql

In file 1, the `JSON` element "image" is nested. The data looks like structured like this:

```
{"id": "0001", "type": "donut", "name": "Cake", "image":{"url": "images/0001.jpg", "width": 200, "height": 200}}
```

Resulting schema is correctly inferred by Spark:

```
val df1 = spark.read.json("/xxx/xxxx/xxxx/nested1.json")
df1.printSchema

root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- image: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- height: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- url: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- width: long (nullable = true)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- type: string (nullable = true)
```

File nested2.json contains some nested elements and some non-nested (below the second line, element "image" is not nested):

```
{"id": "0001", "type": "donut", "name": "Cake", "image":{"url": "images/0001.jpg", "width": 200, "height": 200}}
{"id": "0002", "type": "donut", "name": "CupCake", "image": "images/0001.jpg"}
```

Resulting schema does not contain the nested data:

```
val df2 = spark.read.json("/xxx/xxx/xxx/nested2.json")
df2.printSchema

root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- image: string (nullable = true)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- type: string (nullable = true)
```

Why is Spark not able to figure out the schema when non-nested elements are present?

How to process a `JSON` file containing a mixture of records like this using Spark and Scala?

Comment: The second record is not a nested one so it will take the schema of the second only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By not specifying a schema, Spark will infer it from the data source by reading the data once. Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/0946a9514f56565c78b0555383c1ece14aaf2b7b/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/json/JsonInferSchema.scala#L48-L53) for inference of `json` data, there is a comment in the code:

> Infer the type of a collection of json records in three stages:
>
> - 1. Infer the type of each record
> - 2. Merge types by choosing the lowest type necessary to cover equal keys
> - 3. Replace any remaining null fields with string, the top type

In other words, **only the most general data type** is returned when there are differences. By mixing nested and un-nested types, only the un-nested will be returned, as all rows contain these values.

---

Instead of infering the schema, create it yourself and supply it to the method.

```
val schema = StructType( 
  StructField("id", StringType, true) ::
  StructField("type", StringType, true) ::
  StructField("name", StringType, true) ::
  StructField(
    "image",
    StructType( 
      StructField("height", LongType, true) ::
      StructField("url", StringType, true) ::
      StructField("width", LongType, true) ::
      Nil
    ))
  ) :: Nil
)
```

Then use the schema when reading:

```
val df2 = spark.read
  .schema(schema)
  .json("/xxx/xxx/xxx/nested2.json")
```

However, this approach will result in *null* for the "image" field when it is simply a string. To get both types, read the file twice and merge the results.

```
val df3 = spark.read
  .json("/xxx/xxx/xxx/nested2.json")
```

The new dataframe has a different schema then the first. Let's make them equal and then merge the dataframes together:

```
val df4 = df3.withColumn("image", 
    struct($"image".as("url"), 
           lit(0L).as("height"), 
           lit(0L).as("width"))
  .select("id", "type", "name", "image")

val df5 = df2.union(df4)
```

The last `select` is to make sure the columns are in the same order as `df2`, otherwise the `union` will fail.